# Custom Login using a Third Parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a relatively simple login system for Symfony2.

I have the basics down and working just fine.

What makes this a bit special is I need a way to provide a third value (an ecosystem value). The user names in my database are not unique on their own, but make unique pairs with an ecosystem value.

The ecosystem value is provided by the form that they log in from.

How can I use this ecosystem value be taken into consideration when performing a login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Cookbook tutorial on [How to load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) - specifically the part about [Authenticating Someone with a Custom Entity Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider).

This part explains how to alter/create a `UserProviderInterface` to allow logging in via an e-mail address or username. Obviously, this isn't what you want, but - it should be relatively trivial to modify the code to also query/validate against your 3rd login parameter.

Ideally, you will probabaly want to create your own UserProvider and luckily, there is a cookbook tutorial just for that: [How to create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html).

---

**Update:** To have the 3rd login option handled and passed to your custom providers (created above), you will also need to create a custom Authentication Provider. Take a look at (yet another) cookbook article on [How to create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html). This article is tailored for handling extra request header parameters for authentication, but using this example you should be able to swap out request headers for request POST values.

Use the cookbook article to get an understanding of how authentication with Symfony2 works, but use (and extend) the username/password functionality of Symfony2 and just include your 3rd parameter. Some classes to look at:

- [UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php)
- [UsernamePasswordToken](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php)
- [UserAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php)

Comment: I already have both of those implemented. The thing I can't figure out is how to get the third value to my repository in order to validate against it.

Comment: @samanime: I've updated my answer, I hope it provides some assistance! If you do nothing else, take a look at and mimic the `UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener` class I posted a link to. Good luck!

Comment: Well, that was a lot of work but I finally got it. I had to implement my own Authentication listener, Authentication provider, token and factory. I extended the UsernamePassword version for most of them, so I didn't have to reimplement the security stuff it already has in place. 

I also couldn't find a way to get a second value into an EntityRepository, so I had to pass in an array in the first parameter to get what I needed in there. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: could you post your solution? There are very few code samples one can find about authenticating against multiple parameters. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom [Password Authenticator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_password_authenticator.html) (>= Symfony 2.6) and set attributes there:

1. createToken(): Create the token (you can use UsernamePasswordToken) and set attribute to it, take the needed data from $request.
2. authenticateToken(): Here you do something with this 3rd variable ($token->getAttribute()). If it affects loadUserByUsername read below.

In authenticateToken() you have UserProvider and loadUserByUsername. What I did was use [my user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) (which extends FOSUserBundle and overrides the said method) and pass an array to it with username and the other needed data. Don't forget to check what is passed inside loadUserByUsername (e.g. if it's a string, then call parent::loadUserByUsername).

I am sure that this trick with loadUserByUsername is bad one, but I don't know how else could it be done.